# binding a ng-repeat child object to another child object (zipcode +city!)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

Mainly psuedo code so please dont mind if there's typos.  I'm trying to figure out how to access the value of address.City.ZipCode for my controller method; since this is just a child in the address iteration  (marked as (???)).  The objective is to filter the cities by the zipcode.

Seems simple but it really has me stumped.  Maybe there is an array like syntax for $scope.address.City.ZipCode?  The reason for the ng-repeat is I intend to have a large list of addresses in each account.

THANK YOU FRIENDS

.

view.html

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses">

    <select ng-model="address.City.Id" ng-options:(cityList.id as cityList.name)>
    </select>

    <input type="text" ng-model="address.City.ZipCode" ng-change="getCityByZip()" />

</div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.getCityByZip = function () {

   $http.get("http://localhost/GetCitiesByZipCode?zip=" + (???) ).success(function (data) {
            $scope.cityList = data; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this problem by many ways let me just show one  of those dummy code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="address.City.ZipCode" ng-change="getCityByZip($index)" />

$scope.getCityByZip = function (index) {

   $http.get("http://localhost/GetCitiesByZipCode?zip="+$scope.addresses[index].City.zipCode ).success(function (data) {
            $scope.cityList = data; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay Ben, I whipped a fiddle together and that method worked out well, looks like I have an issue elsewhere though and I'm not getting any values even with the correct syntax :(.